# Apache2 server becomes overloaded and unresponsive quickly after restart

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4

I am a beginner system admin at best I have been running my AWS ec2 instance for a long time without incident. It mainly powers my iOS and web application and its web connections.

Recently I had to update the iOS web service framework that I use and once that update went live I've been having server outages. I can SSH into my instance but any outside connection attempt either through iOS server calls or web access infinitely loads.

I've communicated back and forth with AWS support and they said my NetworkIn looked a bit high. My current solution has been when it goes down, restart the server and it generally goes back up for a little while but as of the last couple days my traffic has spiked dramatically because of the new years and after restarting it will only stay accessible for a minute, tops.

I increased my MaxRequestWorkers from 150 -> 250 and so far that has been the only thing that has kept my server accessible. I just did this and at this point it has remained active for ~30 minutes without incident.

I'm not sure what could be the root cause of even where to look to solve it or to hire someone to try and help me solve it.

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated and if you need anymore information please let me know

Comment: The answer below provides a good starting point. If you're unable to determine what's going on, though, drop me a line at the email on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

There's no a single approach to your problem. It could be a DoS or just a misconfiguration. It could be anything related to Apache (or not).
I can tell what I usually do:

1. ***Is It really Apache the main cause***? As you just said about a network-in traffic (not specifically web), just double-check it using a software like `top` or `htop` (that I prefer). You will have a list of processes that you can order following different criteria. You can also see which is the busy part of the system (CPU, memory, ...).
2. Ok, It's Apache, but: ***what's causing this peak of resource usage***?

   - **Access Log**: take a look at the access log (`/var/log/apache2/access.log` if you have an `Ubuntu`). Is it, for example, plenty of error codes with strange requests? `403 - Forbidden`, `404 - Not found`. If so, you could be under the attack of an automated tool. This is a very general explanation (I want to underline this point), but after some time you'll be able to understand it from the logs (take a look at [Identify DDoS from Apache logs](http://www.apacheviewer.com/using-apache-logs-viewer-to-identify-denial-of-service-ddos-attack/) for example
   - **Logs**: other than trying to follow the stream of logs, try to analyze it with a tool built for that. I like `GoAccess`. It' a very simple and power tool that scan your `Apache` logs and makes some useful statistics (good explanation here [GoAccess webpage](https://goaccess.io/)
   - **Apache stats**: you could use the `mod_status`. This is an `Apache` module that creates some statistics about your webserver, for you. You can access those statistics connecting to a webpage and consulting it (this is a good explanation for its usage [mod_status tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/)
   - **Other causes**: are resources really busy? Or you have just many `Apache` processes waiting for an answer from, for example, the `DB` ? In most cases, the `DB` is the bottleneck of web architectures. Maybe is overloaded and it's not responding in time to requests because, for example, you have a blocking query on a specific table. Try to check it using `netstat -atulnp | grep apache`, taking a look at the destination and the status of all requests

It would really be a list of infinite tasks to do. These are the starting ones (IMHO). If you post more detailed information, I can be more specific for your case.